Nest js Files Validation Issue
I'm working on a NestJS application where I need to handle the upload of multiple image files (nic_front, nic_back, live_photograph) and validate them based on file type (JPEG or PNG) and file size (up to 2MB). I've tried using FileFieldsInterceptor for file handling and ImageFileValidationPipe for validation, but it seems to only work for a single file at a time.
Here's my current setup:
@Patch('/register')
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileFieldsInterceptor([
      { name: 'nic_front', maxCount: 1 },
      { name: 'nic_back', maxCount: 1 },
      { name: 'live_photograph', maxCount: 1 },
    ]),
  )
  registerAdmin(
    @UploadedFiles(ImageFileValidationPipe)
    files: {
      nic_front?: Express.Multer.File[];
      nic_back?: Express.Multer.File[];
      live_photograph?: Express.Multer.File[];
    },
    @Body() data: any,
  ) {
    // code
  }

And here's my ImageFileValidationPipe:
import { FileTypeValidator, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  MaxFileSizeValidator,
  ParseFilePipe,
  ParseFileOptions,
} from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class ImageFileValidationPipe extends ParseFilePipe {
  constructor(options?: ParseFileOptions) {
    super({
      ...options,
      validators: [
        new MaxFileSizeValidator({
          maxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024, // 2MB
          message: 'File size exceeds the limit of 2MB.',
        }),
        new FileTypeValidator({
          fileType: '^image\\/(jpeg|png)$',
        }),
      ],
    });
  }
}

However, this setup only validates one file at a time and doesn't handle multiple files properly. How can I modify my validation logic or pipe to handle multiple file uploads and validate each file individually based on my criteria? Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated!
